# Permalink change made author archive vanished

Tags: permalinks, 404-error

I changed my WordPress blog URL from:

```
http://example.com/%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%postname%/
```

into first,

```
http://example.com/%postname%/
```

and then after many days,

```
http://example.com/%post_id%/%postname%/
```

But now seen that, they are taking the author archive link to a dead end (404). Where the default author archive link is: `/?author=1`, with any of these permalinks, the author archive's link becomes `/author/1`. But the URL is taking me to a 404. I've tested in my local dev environment too, can't get what's the exact URL which can give me the author archive.

The author archive link, that's in my theme is:

```
<a href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url( false, $authordata->ID, $authordata->user_nicename ); ?>">
   <?php the_author(); ?>
</a>
```

Is that a bug of WordPress or I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your [`get_author_posts_url()`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_author_posts_url/) seems wrong, it doesn't accept three parameters. Passing ID as first one should be sufficient to generate correct link, name argument is pretty redundant there.

Comment: Thanks @rarst. Just changed function to `<?php echo get_author_posts_url( $authordata->ID, $authordata->user_nicename ); ?>` and yala. Removed the `false, ` part. SOLVED! :)